# how to generate a custom id for specific type of users when that user signup via django model form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

models.py

```
 class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

username = None
email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True) 
mobileno = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)    
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)

id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
userid= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

objects = UserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email


def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.vendor == True and self.is_superuser == False:                                   
        if not self.userid: 
            self.userid = "VEN" + str(self.id + (10 ** 5))  # generating the uid and allocating the value
            self.userid.save()
        else:
            pass                                        
    else:
        pass
```

forms.py

```
 class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
"""
A Custom form for creating new users.
"""

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ['email','first_name','last_name','mobileno']

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.customer = True
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user




 """ For Vendor users forms"""
 class VendorCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ['email','first_name','last_name','mobileno']


def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit=False)
    user.vendor = True
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

views.py

```
  #Vendor Signup
  def VendorSignup(request):
     vendorform = VendorCreationForm()
     if request.method == 'POST':
         vendorform = VendorCreationForm(request.POST)        

         if vendorform.is_valid():
             new_user = vendorform.save()
             new_user.is_active = False
             new_user.save()
             return redirect('login')
     else:
         vendorform = VendorCreationForm()


     return render(request, 'vendor/signup.html', {'vendorform': vendorform})
```

I want to generate a customID (that starts with VEND0001)for the vendor users only when (they're signup with vendorform) and shouldn't generated customid for customers and superuser. I have an error in models. Can someone please, solve this for me.

I have facing issues (UNIQUE constraint failed: customer_customuser.userid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I think when you do:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.vendor == True and self.is_superuser == False:                                   
        if not self.userid: 
            self.userid = "VEN" + str(self.id + (10 ** 5))  # generating the uid and allocating the value
            self.userid.save()
        else:
            pass                                        
    else:
        pass
```

In super().save there is no userid information which is obligatory.
Maybe `userid= models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True)` will work... But be aware that NULL != NULL.

Then change
`if not self.userid` to `if self.userid is None:`

Comment: `self.save()` instead of `self.userid.save()` is working properly. Thanks, dude. One more question i have, Is it possible to create that id like this `VEN0001` the zero before integer 1 and then it incremented like `VEN0002`+.

Comment: You mean something like this?
```req_length = 4<br/>
for id_number in range(0,20):
    number_of_lacked_zeros = req_length-len(str(id_number))
    print("VEN"+"0"*number_of_lacked_zeros+str(id_number))```

Comment: Yes, like that. but, is it work with that field and the number may be increased like 10k plus.? or can I use 1 +  or 100+

Comment: self.userid="VEN"+ lacked_zeros + str(int(self.userid.replace("VEN",""))+increment_number)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. @Wojciech Gadaszewski

Comment: hi. I need your help with this in the same question. In the user model there are customers and vendors that are both registered. userid generated for vendors only. the problem I am facing, if vendor there`VEN1002`, again customer or superuser registered. userid won't be generated. but if again one vendor registered, id generated as`VEN1004`. I need this `VEN1003` likewise. Not customers and superusers counts must not be added.

Comment: Use `CustomUser.objects.filter(vendor=True).count()` instead of `id`

Comment: the exact output I get. but one small issue, when the table is empty, I registered the first vendoruser, it created userid as `VEN002`. I need `VEN001`. Sorry, for asking for small doubts. I can't do that. 

my model.py is `if self.userid is None:vid = CustomUser.objects.filter(vendor=True).count() self.userid = "VEN00" + str(vid + 1) self.save() else:  pass `

Comment: count() - 1 will work?

Comment: I don't know to write the condition for this. (table is empty create vendor user id is `VEN001`). except for this, all is worked fine.